# Права доступа к файлам, часть 2

Tags: php, администрирование

Короче,я понял, что на localhost, работая под виндовз, нет возможности установить права доступа к файлам и каталогам? Игрался я chmod и так и эдак, все равно можно просмотреть содержимое каталога, набрав его имя в адресной строке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если память не изменяет то в настройках виртул хостов(апача) или в htaccess можно добавить 
Options -Indexes

к правам на папки это не имеет отношения

Answer (score 1):

камрад [[@Александр Смага](/users/3421/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0)](/users/3421/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) правильно подсказал. А права на папки/файлы под виндой не выставить... Поставьте VirtualBox например и закатайте туда Linux.

Comment: А если я размещаю свой сайт с каталогами и файлами на хосте, я должен сам устанавливать права доступа, или все в руках владельца хоста? Может вопрос глупый, но обычно я занимаюсь техническим программированием - там, крестики-нолики, дочки-матери и т.д.)) Поэтому тонкостей хостинга не знаю.

Comment: смотрите, в linux подобных системах есть группы пользователей.
Допустим владелец папки пользователь ftp он в группе www-data в которой так же находится пользователь apache
права на файлы 755 т.е пользователь ftp может редактировать(и выполнять), а apache только читать. в windows тоже есть права но они не слишком удачно реализваны(во всяком случае в XP)

Comment: Так как с реальным хостом? Если я размещаю свой сайт на реальном хостинге, значит я являюсь owner и сам устанавливаю права на свои каталоги?

Comment: конечно но в группе у вас уже будут пользватели такие как апач и т.д.